# How can I add a filesystem to my HTTP-listener/ add frameworks in C#

Tags: c#, http, frameworks, httplistener

I have an Http-listener in c#. It listens on `http://{ip-address}:8080/index/`. I can send websites as response to httpclients in the form of strings, and when opening the uri in the browser I get the string (html for example). But now I have a javascript framework I want to use. To show it locally in the browser I can just use `<script src="../p5.min.js"></script>` for example. But the framework obviously doesn't get sent by the Http-listener. How can I do something like this. I know, that there are other C# frameworks for this knd of tasks, but most of my application relies on the Http-listener because it mostly consists of api-calls.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.  Maybe if you stated, step by step, what you would like your application to do?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have a Http-listener in c#.  Until now, I only used it to do api similar stuff. But now I want it to show a websites when called. So basically, when opening the prefixes specified in the listener it should respond with an html website. Thats just what this example does: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.8. But I also want to use javascript frameworks. These are saved as files. To run them locally you just need to put <script src="../p5.min.js"></script> in your html file, and then you can use it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the question sounds like "how to implement HTTP server that supports file downloads"... which already have answers on SO... Granted there is no difference between "response in form of strings" and "response in form of strings that represent JavaScript", but if OP wants files...

Comment: "But the framework obviously doesn't get sent by the Http-listener" but it should, that is you problem. Do you get a 404?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yeah, that's not what it sounds like to me.  It sounds to me like he wants to build a CodePen clone.

Comment: @RobertHarvey hmm... Interesting way of reading it... but now I see how it could be the case. I'd probably join on "unclear" vote, but since there was none I decided that duplicate of how I read the question would do. OP still can [edit] to clarify (if they care).